# "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again" when login in responsinator.com

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, laravel

My project is running fine, but when I run the project locally on any emulator to check mobile responsiveness and try to login I get an error of:

> The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.

I tried to solve this via Git but the problem is still here. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: It seems that you are trying with expired csrf token

Comment: any solution???

Comment: You need to add `{{ csrf_field() }}` after `<form>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Add the following blade directive to your form

```
@csrf
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf

Comment: i hav euse @csrf but still same problem is here

Comment: Could you update your question with some code? Add the form, the routes and the controller

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes from the CSRF token verification which fails. So either you're not posting one or you're posting an incorrect one.

The reason it works for GET is that for a GET route in Laravel, there is no CSRF token posted.

You can either post a CSRF token in your form by calling:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Or

```
@csrf
```

Or exclude your route (NOT RECOMMENDED DUE TO SECURITY) in :

> app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
protected $except = [
    'your/route'
];
```